# Puts statement in function is not executed, function test fails, but receive(:function) spec works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-models

In my model definition, I have

```rb
# models/my_model.rb

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: my_models
#
#  id               :bigint           not null, primary key
#  another_model_id :bigint
#  field_1          :string
#  field_2          :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_my_models_on_another_model_id  (another_model_id) UNIQUE

class MyModel < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :another_model

  def update_from_api_response(api_response)
    $stderr.puts("UPDATE")
    self.field_1 = api_response[:field_1]
    self.field_2 = api_response[:field_2]
  end

  def update_my_model!(api_response)
    ApplicationRecord.transaction do
      $stderr.puts("HELLO")
      update_from_api_response(api_response)
      $stderr.puts("WORLD")
      self.save!
    end
  end
end
```

I put in some `puts` statements to check whether my code entered the function. If everything works alright, the program should log "HELLO", "UPDATE", then "WORLD".

In my model spec I have

```rb
# spec/models/my_model_spec.rb

RSpec.describe MyModel, type: :model do
  let(:my_model) { create(:my_model) }
  let(:api_response) {
    {
      :field_1 => "field_1",
      :field_2 => "field_2",
    }
  }

  describe("update_my_model") do
    it "should update db record" do
      expect(my_model).to receive(:update_from_api_response)
          .with(api_response)
      expect(my_model).to receive(:save!)
      expect{ my_model.update_my_model!(api_response) }
        .to change{ my_model.field_1 }
    end
  end
end
```

The factory object for `MyModel` is defined like this (it literally does not do anything)

```rb
# spec/factories/my_models.rb

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_model do

  end
end
```

The output from the `puts` (this appears before the error message)

```sh
HELLO
WORLD
```

Interestingly, "UPDATE" is not printed, but it passes the `receive` test.

The `change` match test fails, and the output from the console is as follows

```sh
1) MyModel update_my_model should update db record
     Failure/Error:
       expect{ my_model.update_my_model(api_response) }
        .to change{ my_model.field_1 }

       expected `my_model.field_1` to have changed, but is still nil
     # ./spec/models/my_model_spec.rb
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb
```

I suspected that it might have something to do with me wrapping the update within `ApplicationRecord.transaction do` but removing that does nothing as well. "UPDATE" is not printed in both cases.

I've also changed the `.to receive(:update_from_api_response)` to `.to_not receive(:updated_from_api_response)` but it throws an error saying that the function was called (but why is "UPDATE" not printed then?). Is there something wrong with the way I'm updating my functions? I'm new to Ruby so this whole `self` syntax and whatnot is unfamiliar and counter-intuitive. I'm not sure if I "updated" my model field correctly.

Thanks!

Link to Git repo: https://github.com/jzheng13/rails-tutorial.git

Comment: Can you post the above in a minimal rails app on git hub with just those things and nothing else - that would make it really easy for someone to simply download and debug.

Comment: Also update_from_api_response is missing an 'end' keyword

Comment: That was a copy and paste error. It's now fixed.

Comment: Also updated question with link to repo.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `expect(my_model).to receive(:update_from_api_response).with(api_response)` it actually overrides the original method and does not call it.

You can call `expect(my_model).to receive(:update_from_api_response).with(api_response).and_call_original` if you want your original method to be called too.

Anyway, using "expect to_receive" and "and_call_original" rings some bells for me, it means you are testing two different methods in one test and the tests actually depends on implementation details instead of an input and an output. I would run two different tests: test that "update_from_api_response" changes the fields you want, and maybe test that "update_my_model!" calls "update_from_api_response" and "save!" (no need to test the field change, since that would be covered on the "update_from_api_response" test).

Comment: I'm not testing `update_from_api_response`. The function I'm testing is `update_my_model` which is supposed to call `update_from_api_response`.

Comment: But the thing is that my actual test tests another method which calls `update_my_model` and then `update_from_api_response`. I also use `receive` to test that `update_from_api_response` is called and the logged output is the same ("HELLO", "WORLD"). So even though `receive` supposedly "replaced the method, it only did so for `update_from_api_response` instead of `update_from_model`.

Comment: I know, that's exactly my point: if you don't want to test `update_from_api_response` on that test, then there's no point on wanting the original code to be called and checking the `field_1` value changed. `update_from_api_response` is responsible for that change, if you don't want to test that method then don't test that change since the method you are actually testing is not responsible of changing that value.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you are testing more things that you should on a single test. You can split the test in smaller tests easier to tests each and you'll have the same coverage with cleaner and more decoupled tests.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really explain the behaviour of the function spec. The exact same thing happens even when I'm testing a function that's one level higher, and `update_my_model` prints "HELLO" and "WORLD" but doesn't print "UPDATE". If that is so, it cannot be that `receive` overrides the function.

Comment: Can you show that higher level test? `expect to receive` does override the method, that's why you have the `and_call_original` method. I guess your higher level test is not exactly the same as the one you have on the question, do you have `expect(...).to receive(:update_my_model!)` on that test?

Comment: Yes I do. The higher level function calls the API and returns the JSON results, with a `rescue` that catches the possible errors that might arise. It also uses `receive` for `update_from_api_response` which is called within the function body.

Comment: I insist, show that test you are talking about since you say it's not the same on the question and you seem to not like the answer but you are not being clear on what does your test really do (you try to explain it, but the actual code will be clear enough).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, the separate Github file works wonders.

## This part works fine:

Put it in a separate expectation and it works fine:

`describe("update_my_model") do
    it "should update db record" do
      # This works
      expect{ my_model.update_my_model!(api_response) }.to change{ my_model.field_one }
    end
  end`

## How is it triggered?

But here is your problem:

`expect(my_model).to receive(:update_from_api_response).with(api_response)
      expect(my_model).to receive(:save!)`

This means that you are expecting my model to have `update_from_api_response` to be called with the `api_response` parameter passed in. But what is triggering that? Of course it will fail. I am expecting my engine to start. But unless i take out my car keys, and turn on the ignition, it won't start. But if you are expecting the car engine to start without doing anything at all - then of course it will fail! Please refer to what @arieljuod has mentioned above.

Also why do you have two methods: `update_from_api_response` and `update_my_model!` which both do the same thing  - you only need one?

Comment: `update_from_api_response` and `update_my_model!` does two different things they don't do the same thing. One calls the other and saves de record inside a transaction. It's a design decision I guess, maybe he calls `update_from_api_response` somewhere else too.